# SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5 Missing operand after 'COLLATE' operator

Tags: sql-server, collation

I am trying to use collate in a SQL query, ADO.NET on SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5.

Here is how I tried but I always get this error:

> System.Data.SyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Missing operand after
>   'COLLATE' operator.

Here is my query:

```
select n.Translation
from Nouns as n
where n.Translation like '%something%' COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Random thought... you wouldn't COLLATE a constant normally. Try this:

```
where n.Translation COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS like '%something%'
```